# react native on reload loads old version

Tags: react-native

I am running react-native run-ios. It has been working fine until today.

I am using "react": "16.9.0", "react-native": "0.61.2".

My problem is when I reload the app in the simulator it goes to an older version of the app. However when I make changes in the code and save, it will reflect the new changes but as soon as I refresh, it runs the old version again.

I have already tried to reboot, clear cache, clear watchman, reinstall node modules.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem occurs because you are running using command line.Please try running your app from xCode by using cmd+R & make sure to

1. Clear node module and re install
2. Disable hot reloading
3. Disable Live
4. reload Disconnect debugger